# check header for Authenticated sender in postfix

Tags: debian, postfix, amavis, smtp-auth

My users send email with SMTP AUTH via SASL Authentification.  Unfortunately their mails would marked as `NoBounceOpenRelay` by Amavis.

So I set this to postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
```

Is it possible to tell amavis checking this email header, so I can use a `policy_bank` to **bounce** or **reject** mails which contain Spam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your case was similar to [this example case on Amavisd documentation](http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/bypassing.html#10)

> If for some reason SASL users connect to port 25, as an alternate method you could have all clients in Postfix' $mynetworks and SASL auth senders bypass checks and let everything else fall through to a catchall that sets the content_filter.

```
#main.cf
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026

smtpd_data_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_pipelining
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/filter-catchall.regexp

# /etc/postfix/filter-catchall.regexp:
/^/ FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

In this mode,

- SASL user will permitted through `permit_sasl_authenticated` so it'll fall into `content_filter` parameter i.e. `content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026`.
- Other email will fall into catchall `check_client_access regexp:/etc/postfix/filter-catchall.regexp`. So, it will go through smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024.

The last part is configuring separate policy bank in port 10024 and 10026.

---

Above setup can be extended to allow whitelisting based on other factor, for example: SASL username and sender domain.

- For SASL username, you can use [check_sasl_access](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sasl_access) before permit_sasl_authenticated. *Note: this feature was available for Postfix 2.11 and later.*

  ```
  # main.cf
  ...
  check_sasl_access hash:/etc/postfix/amavis-bypass-sasl
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  ...


  #/etc/postfix/amavis-bypass-sasl

  # Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain is empty.
  username   FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
  # Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain=example.com.
  username@example.com FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
  ```
- For sender domain, you can use [check_sender_access](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#check_sender_access)

  ```
  # main.cf
  ...
  check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/amavis-bypass-sender
  permit_sasl_authenticated
  ...


  #/etc/postfix/amavis-bypass-sasl

  # Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain is empty.
  internal.example.com   FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
  # Use this when smtpd_sasl_local_domain=example.com.
  whitelist.example.org FILTER smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10026
  ```

Comment: Oh, i did not see that :-(

Comment: And i just got edited my workbook.. The Users should be possible to turn off the filter. So i need a way to Whitelist them. With use of the content_filter, this seems not possible :-(

Comment: Whitelist per IP address or Whitelist per SASL user?

Comment: Per sasl user and/or domain

Comment: See my updated answer about the possibilities of your requirement